# Why is my recursive function erring?

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a recursive function, `dec2base(n, b)`, that returns a list of base `b` digits in the positive integer `n`.  For example.

```
dec2base(120, 10) => [1,2,0] (1 * 10**2 + 2 * 10**1 + 0 * 10**0)
```

Currently I have.

```
def dec2base(n, b):
    if n < 10:
        return [n]
    else:
        return dec2base(n, b) + [n%b]
```

But when I run the program, it returns an infinite loop error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Add some print statements and watch it run. It'll help you see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are not decrementing the value of n at any point in your method, so if you start with any value of n >=10, the loop never ends.

Another observation - the logic of "if n < 10 return [n]" seems not to make sense if b is not equal to 10.  For instance, 9 < 10, but I'm assuming the value of dec2base(9,2) would not be [9].  It would be [1,0,0,1].

Answer (score 2):

Okay, in any recursive function, there has to be some function that goes to zero in order to have something to stop.  In this case, what you want is to really model the way you7 do it by hand:

- divide by the radix (the base)
- put the remainder in as a digite
- recur using the same base, but the  other part of the division.  (The quotient.)

That is, if you are finding the hex value of 1000, you take

dec2base(1000,16):

- if first parameter == 0, return, you're done
- 1000 mod 16 (=8)    -> save the 8
- dec2base(62, 16)   -> recursion step

Now, obviously every time you make the recusion step, the first parameter is smaller, and if you think about it, that eventually *must* go to 0.  So eventually it will terminate.

Here's a real simple version in Python:

```
result = ""

def dec2base(n,b):
    global result
    if n <= 0: return
    result = str(n % b) + result # why am I prepending it?
    dec2base( n // b, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dec2base(1000,8)
    print result
```

Now, if the base is anything > 9 (say 16) you'll need to take care of translating values from 10 to 15 into alpha a-f, and this is purposefully not very elegant because I wanted it to lay out just like the example.

Comment: A recursive function that communicates its result by modifying a global variable? *Seriously*?

Comment: I'm not sure how you think this is laid out like the example? Where did the need for a global variable spring from?

Comment: Yeah, because it gives me the chance to ask the question about prepending.  You don't like it, write your own answer.

Comment: gnibbler, see where it says "save the 8"?  The code corresponds line for line with the bulleted example.

Comment: Why _are_ you prepending it? The only reason I can see is that you are accumulating the result in a global variable instead of the more usual appending it to the result of the recursive call

Answer (score 1):

There's only a couple of tiny mistakes in your solution.

```
def dec2base(n, b):
    if n < b:                            # so it will work for bases other than 10
        return [n]
    else:
        return dec2base(n//b, b) + [n%b] # you're just missing "//b"  here
```

You can simplify it slightly like this

```
def dec2base(n, b):
    if not n:
        return []
    return dec2base(n//b, b) + [n%b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calling `dec2base(n, b)` to infinity. If you call

```
dec2base(20, b)
```

Your function will continue to execute the 2nd branch of your if/else statement. You need to pass a reduced value to your recursive function call so that eventually, `n < 10` will evaluate to True.

Comment: I tried n-1 but that gives the wrong answer. Should i be doing a mathematical styled thing on the n?

Comment: Do `n//b`. Also, your if statement doesn't make any sense. `dec2base(10,2)` would yield [5, 0], which is incorrect. What you want is `if n < b:`